# The difference between series and parallel LC circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

I wanted to know if there is a difference between a series LC circuit and a parallel LC circuit, like these:[image: the resistance of the inductor is so little so it would be ignored]

I noticed that the tuned circuit is all the time a series LC circuit, and I wondered if it could be a parallel LC circuit. 
Also, I wanted to know if the series LC circuit works excatly as a parallel LC circuit (regarding the way they interchange the energy between both of them).

Comment: "I noticed that the tuned circuit is all the time a **series** LC circuit" Not in my Universe.

Comment: Series and parallel LC are certainly not the same; e.g. serial is a short circuit at resonance, parallel is open circuit at resonance.

Comment: @JImDearden, OK, maybe in my humble text book and humble conclusion. Anyways, I would like it if you shared your knowledge about it.

Comment: @Chu, excuse me, I didn't get it, could you please explain it for me?

Comment: The equations are different, did you look at the wiki on RLC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both parallel and series L-C circuits are used.  They have opposite impedance characteristics of each other.

A inductor and capacitor in series has infinite impedance at 0 and infinite frequency, and 0 impedance at the resonant frequency.

A inductor and capacitor in parallel has 0 impedance at 0 and infinite frequency, and infinite impedance at the resonant frequency.

You don't have to just remember which case is which.  You can easily see from inspection whether the circuit has zero or infinite impedance at zero or infinite frequency.  In the series case, the impedance will obviously be infinite at DC due to the capacitor.  The inductor likewise has infinite impedance at infinite frequency.  In the parallel case, the inductor is a short at DC and the capacitor a short at infinite frequency.

Answer (score 1):

To store energy, a circulating path must exist. The parallel LC has that path. A CLC PI (or LCL PI) also provide that circulating path. Hence well-intentioned VDD filtering with 2 caps in parallel and the inevitable small wiring/trace inductance between the 2 caps......is also a resonator. Consider 100uF and 0.1uf in parallel (will not resonate), connected with 4" wire on a breadboard.
We expect low impedances, but a high-frequency peak in impedance will occur; value of 100UF in series with 0.1uF is 0.1uF (minus 0.1%), which resonates with 0.1uH (4" wiring) to ring/resonate at 1.59MHz. Is this easy to dampen?
Z(0.1uF at 1.59MHz) = 1.00 ohms, so this is difficult to dampen. {at times, the ESR of the 2 capacitors, or even PCB trace resistance, is adequate to achieve Q=1 or 2. The necessary Rdampen is 2*sqrt(L/C) for Q=1 ; knowing Omega_Ring is 1/sqrt(L*C) and Zl = Omega_Ring * L, we substitute and wanting R = Zl for Q=1, we find R = Zl = (1/sqrt(L*C)) * L = sqrt(L/C) }

Now consider the series LC resonant circuit. [Shorting the source produces a parallel LC, which will store energy.] Simply inserting a seriesLC into a random point of a larger circuit, and expecting a null in voltage at Fresonant is poor design because the seriesLC impedance will interact with the larger circuit's impedances and produce surprises, unless the larger circuit is resistive at frequencies near the resonance; any extra L or C will shift the null's frequency. Any resistance will reduce the nulling, by dampening.